# Multiplicity of intersection of $y^2=x^3$ and $x^2=y^3$ at the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, localization, intersection-theory, local-rings

Those curves intersect at the origin with multiplicity 4, if I did everything correctly. In fact, parametrizing by $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ the first curve and plugging into the second, yields $t^4=t^9$, i.e. $t^4(t^5-1)=0$ and one can see the multiplicity of $t=0$ being $4$.

However, if I try the algebraic geometry approach, by calculating locale Rings, I get a different result and I cannot figure out where I'm making a mistake.

First,
$$\mathbb{K}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3) \cong \mathbb{K}[t^2,t^3]$$

Then,
$$\mathbb{K}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3,x^2-y^3) \cong$$ $$\mathbb{K}[t^2,t^3]/(t^4-t^9) = \mathbb{K}[t^2,t^3]/(t^4(1-t^5)) $$

Now localizing at the origin, $1-x^5$ becomes a unit and thus the final localized ring is:
$$\mathbb{K}[x,y]_P/(y^2-x^3,x^2-y^3) \cong$$ $$\mathbb{K}[t^2,t^3]/(t^4) = \{a+bt^2+ct^3\}$$

But this is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ of dimension 3, instead of 4. Where is my error?

Comment: Another possible calculation: if you extend them to projective curves then there turn out to be no intersections on the "line at infinity".  So, the two curves have a total of $3 \cdot 3$ intersection points counting multiplicities.  The other intersections are $(e^{2\pi i n/5}, e^{-2\pi i n/5})$ for $n \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$, and each should have multiplicity 1.  So, the intersection at the origin is left to have multiplicity 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your calculation, the error you made is that in the ring $\mathbb{K}[t^2, t^3]$, $t^5$ is not in the ideal generated by $t^4$.  Therefore, the correct basis for the vector space $\mathbb{K}[t^2, t^3] / \langle t^4 \rangle$ should in fact be $\{ 1, t^2, t^3, t^5 \}$.

Comment: Omg, I totally missed that. I did $t^5=t\cdot t^4=0$ but obviously I cannot multiply by $t$ which is not in the ring. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

Just localize $\mathbb K[x,y]$ at the origin. Letting $I=(y^2-x^3,x^2-y^3)$, we have $x^3\equiv xy^3\pmod I$ and so $y^2-x^3\equiv y^2(1-xy)\pmod I$ and, similarly, $x^2-y^3\equiv x^2(1-xy)\pmod I$. Since $(1-xy)$ is invertible in the local ring, we have $\mathbb K[x,y]_0/I \cong \mathbb K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ as a vector space, as desired.

Comment: So in other words, it turns out $xy \notin I$ even after localizing, even though $xy$ corresponds to $t^5$ and what corresponds to $t^4$ *is* in $I$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wonder where I went wrong. I'm pretty sure there's an error in my last step. Maybe localizing $\mathbb{K}[t^2,t^3]$ makes the linear term $t$ come back somehow. I'm not very familiar yet with localizations.